# Why does my SO Careers page say "Page Not Found" when I have created my profile page?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, stack-overflow-jobs

I created a [SO Careers Profile Page](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/SathiyaKumarVM) yesterday. I have finished and submitted my profile. I got a confirmation mail, but when I clicked that link it directed me to a page which is not found. I also tried to open my Profile Page but it's saying "Page Not Found".

Why it is not found?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. I wont add this as answer since I am not sure myself, but I think the page will work once the team has reviewed the profile and accepted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple of different things happening here.

First, the email you received was for email verification. That step is required, but verifying your email does not automatically make you searchable by employers or make your profile public. (We require email verification because we notify you by email when employers contact you, and you have the option to reply by email...so making sure that your email address is correct is an important step.)

A profile URL that says "page not found" means that your profile is set to private. You've created a custom URL for your profile page, but you still need to go into your settings (when you're logged in, click "my profile", then on the right hand side of the page you, should see a button that says "profile settings"; click that) and click the "make my profile public" button. That should solve it.

There's one last step here...since your profile is new, you submitted it for verification by the Stack Overflow team. This step *shouldn't* affect whether your profile is public, but I'll look into it more and see if there's a bug there. The review of your profile by the team only affects whether companies can find your profile when they are searching our candidate database, and therefore whether companies can send you messages. It's supposed to be possible for you to have a public profile (visible to anyone you send the link to) without being verified, but it's possible that something's broken there. I'll update here if we find a bug in that process.

Comment: @laura Thanks for your quick response. As you said I changed the profile settings as 'make my profile public' and it's working fine :)

Comment: But I don't understand why the e-mail verification link redirecting to  a page 'Page Not Found' instead of a random page says 'Your email ID has been verified successfully' which is a very common practice in other sites?