# How can I make sure that my Career Profile has been verified by SO team?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, stack-overflow-jobs, accounts

I have created my [Stack Overflow Career profile](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/SathiyaKumarVM) 1 week ago. At that time my profile was under review. As answered by [Laura](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306209/2500920) for one of my question, our profile will be verified by SO team and I hope there will be no specific time period for this verification. Now my question is How can I make sure that my account has been verified by SO team? Will I get any mail confirmation like "Your account has been verified by SO Team" or Will I get message to my Career account?

When I clicked My Profile button in my Career account, my profile page opened with a URL parameter `verified=False#`
i.e. `https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/295534?verified=False#`

[image]

[image]

Does it is a way to make sure that my Profile has not been verified yet?

Comment: You were approved 1 week ago, and I confirmed that you actually show up in search results. We're still looking into why you didn't get a confirmation and what that param is doing in the URL.

Comment: The `verified=False` part seems to appear in every URL - I got it in my profile too, and I assume there's nothing wrong with it, as I've already got messages from potential employers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things:

- **Your profile is in fact verified**. You show up in the candidate database in searches and everything.
- **I've changed the `verified` URL param to be `banner` because it's really only about whether there's a temporary banner notification that appears**. It's not really at all connected to your verification status and is causing a lot of confusion. You are in fact verified.
- **You should have received a confirmation email from us, but were opted out of emails**. It appears you have a record in the database that indicates you opted out from certain emails from us, so when you were approved you didn't receive anything. That being said, I'm looking into whether you should have received this sort of email regardless so this confusion doesn't come up again.

Comment: Good call changing the name of the param.